# C++ nested template error

Tags: c++, sfinae, decltype

I have several templates that check, whether some operator is defined for certain type and I also check for expression return type. When I instantiate this template with certain types, everything is ok, but for some types I get internal compiler error in MSVC. In GCC, I get "template argument is invalid" error. Here is the line causing trouble, when I instantiate post-increment check:

```
template <typename _Type, typename _ReturnType>
static auto test(_Type&& var, _ReturnType&&)
-> decltype(std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<_ReturnType, decltype((var) OPERATOR)>>(), std::true_type());
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Note: OPERATOR is macro expanded to operator I want to check. The whole template is part of bigger macro which I use to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `std::enable_if_t` expects a `bool`, but you don't supply one through `std::is_same`. To get the result of `std::is_same`, you have to access the variable `value` (which has the result of the check).

```
template <typename _Type, typename _ReturnType>
static auto test(_Type&& var, _ReturnType&&)
-> decltype(std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<_ReturnType, decltype((var) OPERATOR)>::value>(), std::true_type());
```

Comment: Don't type traits define `operator()` to return their `::value` value?

Comment: @Rerito they do, but only since C++14